# Super upvote button to reward very high-quality and helpful questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, upvotes

Sometimes I see a question/answer that is of much higher quality (or helped me a lot) than the average SO question/answer, and I'd like to reward the author with more than just 1 upvote (but it's not possible). Should there be a "super upvote" button which gives the OP double rep and increases the post score by 2? Perhaps it should cost the upvoter rep to prevent using this feature too much.

Comment: I think all votes should be equal. Consider a bounty instead.

Comment: This feature already exists, it's called a bounty.

Comment: @RobertLongson Problem 1: Costs too much. Minimum is 50 rep. Problem 2: Bounties are good for rewarding answers but not questions. If you start a bounty to reward a question, you still have to give the rep to an answer. It also does not guarantee that the question gets upvotes from the increased attention due to the bounty.

Comment: As long as we also get a “super downvote” button, I’m on board

Comment: Then we should also have a "super downvote" button, right? .. to downvote very bad question rapidly!

Comment: Then I also want to have "super close votes" ;)

Comment: @honk: we have those, it’s called a dupe-hammer.

Comment: @MartijnPietersm: Correct, but that is not available to me ;) And it only works for closing duplicates.

Comment: have you considered [meta-tag:bounty]?

Comment: Alternatively, we can have a upvote and a half-upvote (with similar effect), but I doubt anybody would want to (or know about) half-upvote.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, we are not going to make some votes “special”. All votes are equal, for good reasons; your opinion on the usefulness of a post should not weigh more than someone else's. If a post is really that great, then other people will surely agree and vote it up too. We don’t need some votes to be “special” for that to happen.

If you feel strongly that not enough people have seen this great post yet you can attract attention to it by setting a bounty. That’ll bring in more people with voting rights and a great post will then surely be voted on more often. Those extra votes carry far more meaning than any special “double” vote ever would.

Also, “double” votes would be wide open for abuse. Fraudulent accounts would just use such super votes to get their sock accounts up to voting strength much more quickly, which then in turn could vote up the master account posts twice as much. At least with bounties, there is far more community visibility to help detect fraudulent use.